# How to change bar color in Echarts

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I'm using Echarts with vue and I created a bar chart and I want to change the color of each bar in this chart. I tried the code below but it just changes the color of the first one.

```
optionYear: {
    legend: {},
    color: ["#14323F", "green", "red", "purple", "yellow", "black"], // tried this to change bar color
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "shadow",
      },
      formatter: function (params) {
        return params[0].data[1] + "%";
      },
    },

    dataset: [
      {
        dimensions: ["name", "value"],

        source: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
      },
      {
        transform: {
          type: "sort",
          config: { dimension: "value", order: "desc" },
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      axisLabel: { interval: 0, rotate: 30 },
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: {
      type: "bar",
      encode: { x: "name", y: "value" },
      datasetIndex: 1,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

To meet your requirement (set color to each x-axis), you should set `itemStyle` function in the `option.series`, here's the code:

```js
option = {
    series: {
      // This is the key part
      itemStyle: {
          color: function (param) {
            const color = ["#14323F", "green", "red", "purple", "yellow", "black"];
            // param.value[0] is the x-axis value
            return color[param.value[0] % color.length]
          }
      },
      type: "bar",
      encode: { x: "name", y: "value" },
      datasetIndex: 1,
    },
    legend: {},
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "shadow",
      },
      formatter: function (params) {
        return params[0].data[1] + "%";
      },
    },
    dataset: [
      {
        dimensions: ["name", "value"],
        source: [[0, 10], [1, 20], [2, 30], [4, 40], [5, 50], [6, 60]],
      },
      {
        transform: {
          type: "sort",
          config: { dimension: "value", order: "desc" },
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      axisLabel: { interval: 0, rotate: 30 },
    },
    yAxis: {},
};
```

It will show like this, each bar of different x-axis will have a different color:

[image]

This `option.color` you set is for different series in the chart, for example, like a chart like this:

[image]